# JS Function that checks if given number belongs to an interval which is closed on the right side

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form>
<input type="number" id="beginning" value=""><label for="beginning"> Beginning of interval</label><br/><br/>
<input type="number" id="ending" value=""><label for="ending"> Ending of interval</label><br/><br/>
<input type="number" id="numberToCheck" value=""><label for="numberToCheck"> Number to check</label><br/><br/>
<input type="button" class="button" value="Check" onclick="check()"><p id="result"></p>
</form>
```

```
function check() {
    const val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("beginning").value);
    const val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("ending").value);
    const val3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("numberToCheck").value);
    const res = document.getElementById("result");
    const check = 
}
```

The function doesn't care if the beginning number is higher than the ending number, meaning
beginning=9 ending=3 and numberToCheck=4 should return true

The function should write out the result in the <p id="result" element
(number is in specified interval or number is not in specified interval)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't need a specific JS function. Just use `if` `else` condition statement.

```js
let check = false

const maxVal = val1 > val2 ? val1 : val2
const minVal = val1 < val2 ? val1 : val2

// check logic
if (val3>minVal && val3<maxVal) {
  check = true
}

res.innerText = check // write out the result
```